# Does anyone has quick "cheat cheat" or "commandline reference" for OSQL?

Tags: sql, osql

a friend of mine complained that SQL managment studio express is prohibited by some security setting set by his system admin.
i recommended to use OSQL

[image]

my question is

i need some basic orders like best way to attach, detach and deal with SQL express databases. any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSDN is always the best source.

[osql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx) on MSDN (with examples).

However, microsoft will *remove* this utility in future versions, so you should start using [`sqlcmd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks Oded, these links are also useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170207.aspx    and     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166559.aspx    and       http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with normal query syntax, it may be easier for you to write queries to .SQL files (edit in notepad and change the extension), then call from osql with either `< filename.sql` or `-i filename.sql`.  Then you also only have to write out the commands once and can reuse them.

Comment: can you clarify with one example i am still beginner but i know SQL insert, delete , select and update

Comment: @mokokamello - I guess what I am saying is, **it is easier to do longer procedures with multiple lines** (insert, then a delete, then an update, or whatever) **if you can write it all out in a text file instead of line by line in osql**